# Getting Slow Motion Video while using QML Media Player

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer

I have been trying to use QML MediaPlayer. So, I start testing the built-in example in Qt Creator (Media Player Example).

After doing some more tests with videos having fps more than 60 (e.g. 120 or 240 fps) I found a weird bug with the media player. The playing video becomes slow-motion! It looks like the fps is always considered 60 or maybe FPSs higher than 120 are not considered!

Note: I have tested with a built-in QML example that is using [QML Media Player](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html). Also I have tested with Qt6.3.4-Msvc2019-64Bit.

Any experience with this issue or any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the frame rate is being clamped to a 60Hz vsync (either real or 'assumed').  I take it that all videos with a frame rate of 60Hz or less are behaving as expected, yes?

Comment: @G.M. I have tested videos with 60FPS and higher fps. In videos with higher framerates, I see the slow-motion issue. However, videos with 60FPS are fine and play normally. Also, I have tested the Qt/C++ MediaPlayer, and it's fine!!!

Comment: @G.M. It seems a rendering issue with QML. Since with c++ it seems ok. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the to disable the vsync and it's better but not perfect.

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile ( QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile );
    format.setRenderableType ( QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLES );
    format.setSwapInterval ( 0 );
    format.setVersion ( 3, 0 );  
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat ( format );
```

UPDATE: I found the reason is the performance of the underlying media service. It seems Qt uses windows native player (e.g. DirectShow). So one solution is to use custome gstreamer pipeline powered by nvidia decoder. So I'm gonna try that and integrate that in qml.

Answer (score 1):

Are You sure you have not set any playbackRate?

Comment: Yes, As I already mentioned I just used the Qt Built-in example.

Comment: Comments/Questions should not be posted as answers.

Comment: question like this should be added in comment